# Display selected data from dynamically created template of radio buttons

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I created a custom directive which accepts data from a controller. What it does is that when called, it dynamically creates a layout of radio buttons.
What I want to do is display the selected data upon clicking the radio button.

my Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('DataController', ['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.gender = {
  label: "Gender",
  required:true,
  valueList: [
  { text: "Male", value: "male" },
  { text:"Female", value:"female" }
  ]
};
$scope.my = { sel: '' };
}]);
```

Directive:

```
 app.directive('appleRadio', function(){
 return {
   restrict: 'E',
   require: 'ngModel',
   scope: {
     fieldOptions: '=options',
     fieldModel: '=ngModel',
     fieldName: '@fieldName',
   },
   controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
   }],
   link: function(scope, element, attribute, controller) {
      element.on('click', function(){
      // test1: assign the selected value to $scope.my.sel in controller
      scope.$parent.my.sel = scope.selected;

      // test2: assign the selected value to ng-model in template
      scope.fieldModel = scope.selected;
      console.log(scope.selected);
    });
  },
  template: '<label style="text-indent: 1em;" ng-repeat="option in   fieldOptions.valueList"> <input type="radio" name="option-{{option.value}}"'+
'id="option-{{value}}" ng-model="$parent.selected" value="{{option.value}}">{{option.text}}'+
'</label>'
 };
});
```

in Index.html:

```
    <div ng-controller="DataController">
            <apple-radio field-label="Gender" field-name="oGend" options="gender" ng-model="selectedOption"></apple-radio>
            <br/>You Selected (via ng-model): {{selectedOption}}<br/>
            You Selected (via controller): {{my.sel}}<br/>
   </div>
```

> **here's the plunker link:**
>
> http://plnkr.co/edit/DBmsFmVXyjuZYE7s9LLa?p=preview

Comment: What's the problem with your code? Why not use the `ng-model` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you make changes to the angular context outside of an angular method/event, you need to call `scope.$apply()`.

So at the end of your onClick handler, call scope.$apply().

Comment: Thank you very much. It actually worked. I'll post the updated answer.